# Find the last 5 characters from string and remove them (if they contain the & sign)

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string. Using PHP (and the easiest solution, probably preg_replace) I want to:

1. Find the last 5 characters (not words) from the string.
2. If one of these last 5 characters contains the '&' character, I want to remove this & character and any other characters that may follow.

For example, when string is:

```
$string='Hello world this day and tomorrow';
```

script should find:

'`orrow`';

(and do nothing since 'orrow' doesn't contain '&').

But when:

`$string='Hello world this day and tomor &row';` or

`$string='Hello world this day and tomo &rrow';` or

`$string='Hello world this day and tomorrow &';` or

`$string='Hello world this day and tomorrow&q';` or

`$string='Hello world this day and tomorrow &co';`

etc. script should remove all characters after & (including &).

Comment: `/(?=.*&).{5}$/` should do

Comment: if & cant be else where, you could jsut use explode

Comment: Do you mean:

$newstring = preg_replace('/(?=.*&).{5}$/', '', $string);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex: `&.{0,4}$` should do the trick. It will find the last 0-4 characters before the end which are after (and including) a & character

```
$string = 'Hello World&foo';
echo $string;
$string = preg_replace('/&.{0,4}$/', '', $string);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid regex, `strpos` might do the trick:

```
$string='Hello world this day and tom&or&row';
if (($pos = strpos ($string, '&', strlen($string) - 5)) !== false)
{
    $string = substr($string,0, $pos);
}
```

**[Ideone](http://ideone.com/q2a7H2) example.**

Comment: You are right, I forgot about that. But strpos also has an offset argument. I'll fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
for($i=max(0, strlen($string)-5);$i<strlen($string);$i++) {
    if($string[$i] == '&') {
        $string = substr($string,0,$i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would leave & in this example (but it should remove &):

`$string='Hello world this day and tomorrow &';`

Comment: I have just tested this and it remove the last & without any trouble.